# Shared DataSource between combobox and textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this three controls:

`ComboBox`: list of myobject

`TextBox`: view a description

`DataSource`: list(of MyObject)

MyObject:

- property id as int
- property combodesctription as string
- property description as string

I want to select an element on the combobox and see the selected object description into the TextBox.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle ComboBox1's SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
If Not IsNothing(ComboBox1.SelectedItem) Then
   Dim obj As MyObject = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, MyObject)
   TextBox1.Text = obj.Description
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//On Combobox Selected Index Change

textbox1.text = Combobox1.Items(1).ToString()
```